# Why does python give me an error when i am importing modules?

Tags: python, import, visual-studio-code

I have installed today Python 3.8.1 (i had 3.7.* months ago, but don´t use it anymore) and I tried to write new code, but I have problems to import modules like matplotlib and so on. It will always mark the module name yellow and says:

> unresolved import ‘matplotlib' Python(unresolved-import)

I checked if python is in the PATH included, I installed/reinstalled the matplotlib module but nothing works. I am using Win 10 64Bit, Python 3.8.1 64Bit and VS Code.

Comment: You have to install matplotlib in the new python installation.

Comment: How do i do that? I am really new to python and i always installed modules using pip

Comment: However you are running python, `python3` or `python3.8` - you can run pip for the exact version of python that you are using by running `python -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: You might also be able to use `pip3.8` depending on how your install is set up.

Comment: `python -m pip freeze` will also tell you which packages are installed for the current interpreter

Comment: if i write `python -m pip freeze` into the command line, it responses nothing

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do that is in a virtualenv, have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

```
python3.8 -m venv env-name # this will create a folder with executables of python, pip.
```

To activate it you can run

```
source env-name/bin/activate # Linux/Mac
env\Scripts\activate.bat # For windows
pip install matplotlib # Matplotlib will be installed for the activated env only
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling python and deleting all existing files from python and installing a new clean version of the newest version of python. After this i used pip to install all required modules to code.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the following command in cmd in admin mode:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

if you are running it on the command prompt after installing the python.